# Change how many stars a rating is out of in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is there any way (via the admin system or module) to change how many stars a product rating is out of? Obviously the default is out of 5, I would like to change it to 10.

I want this so that I can output 'half stars' on five stars in the review details.

Answer (score -1):

This is very simple. You just need to increase your rating box width. Here is the css. You have to increase your width to 140px. By increasing rating box width you can have as many as stars.

```
//Style.css    
.rating-box {
        background: url("../images/bkg_rating.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 transparent;
        font-size: 0;
        height: 13px;
        line-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-indent: -999em;
        width: 140px;
    }
```

Comment: I want to change the values added via the review form, not just the output.

Answer (score -1):

in

> app\design\friendend\your theme\template\review\form.phtml

You will find code like this

```
<table class="data-table" id="product-review-table">
                    <col />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <col width="1" />
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('1 star') ?></span></th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('2 stars') ?></span></th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('3 stars') ?></span></th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('4 stars') ?></span></th>
                            <th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('5 stars') ?></span></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($this->getRatings() as $_rating): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <?php foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option): ?>
                            <td class="value"><input type="radio" name="ratings[<?php echo $_rating->getId() ?>]" id="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode()) ?>_<?php echo $_option->getValue() ?>" value="<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>" class="radio" /></td>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
```

**Please make some changes in the code as below**

**add 5 more** `<col width="1" />`  and

**add 5 more**

```
<th><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('5 stars') ?></span></th>
```

Into corresponding places

it will work

Comment: This just adds 5 more table headers, the values need to be output in the foreach ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option) as well

Comment: Is the output of  ($_rating->getOptions() as $_option) is 10 or 5?

Comment: It's 5, it's set in the core ratings module, that's what I want to be able to modify.